# Opening Word document with Office Interop in J# Error VJS1252

Tags: ms-word, interop, ms-office, j#

I'm attempting to open and read text from a Word document in J#, using Office interop.

The intellisense tip for the first parameter is `/** @ref */Object fileName`. If I pass it a String with an Object typecast, I get error `VJS1252: Actual parameter for byref 'Object' must be assignable`. I'm not sure what this means and I can't find any useful references to this error online.

ex:

```
String fileName = "c:\\document.doc";

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document document = word.getDocuments().Open((object)fileName, ...
```

throws the error. I've already written the rest of the program in J#, everything else, including Excel interop, has gone well; but I'm completely stuck with this problem with Word.

Answer (score 0):

Ahah, figured it out. for anyone else that has this problem, you can't typecast inside the function call. So I had to do

```
Object file = (object)fileName;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document document = word.getDocuments().Open(file, ...
```